# Fine-tune BERT model by removing unused layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sentiment-analysis, bert-language-model

I came across this code for BERT sentiment analysis where the unused layers are removed, Update trainable vars/trainable weights are added and I am looking for documentation which shows what are the different layers in bert, how can we remove the unused layers, add weights, etc. However, I am unable to find any documentation for this.

```
BERT_PATH = "https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1"
MAX_SEQ_LENGTH = 512

class BertLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, bert_path, n_fine_tune_encoders=10, **kwargs,):
    self.n_fine_tune_encoders = n_fine_tune_encoders
    self.trainable = True
    self.output_size = 768
    self.bert_path = bert_path
    super(BertLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)     
  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.bert = tf_hub.Module(self.bert_path,
                              trainable=self.trainable, 
                              name=f"{self.name}_module")
    # Remove unused layers
    trainable_vars = self.bert.variables
    trainable_vars = [var for var in trainable_vars 
                              if not "/cls/" in var.name]
    trainable_layers = ["embeddings", "pooler/dense"]

    # Select how many layers to fine tune
    for i in range(self.n_fine_tune_encoders+1):
        trainable_layers.append(f"encoder/layer_{str(10 - i)}")

    # Update trainable vars to contain only the specified layers
    trainable_vars = [var for var in trainable_vars
                              if any([l in var.name 
                                          for l in trainable_layers])]

    # Add to trainable weights
    for var in trainable_vars:
        self._trainable_weights.append(var)
    for var in self.bert.variables:
        if var not in self._trainable_weights:# and 'encoder/layer' not in var.name:
            self._non_trainable_weights.append(var)
    print('Trainable layers:', len(self._trainable_weights))
    print('Non Trainable layers:', len(self._non_trainable_weights))

    super(BertLayer, self).build(input_shape)
 
  def call(self, inputs):  
    inputs = [K.cast(x, dtype="int32") for x in inputs]
    input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids = inputs
    bert_inputs = dict(input_ids=input_ids, 
                       input_mask=input_mask, 
                       segment_ids=segment_ids)
    
    pooled = self.bert(inputs=bert_inputs, 
                       signature="tokens", 
                       as_dict=True)["pooled_output"]

    return pooled

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], self.output_size)

model = build_model(bert_path=BERT_PATH, max_seq_length=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, n_fine_tune_encoders=10)
```

Can anyone please point me to where I can find resources to learn the different layers in bert, how to remove some layers, add weights, how many layers to fine-tune, etc.?

Comment: this code does not remove layers from tfhub model - the comment is misleading

Comment: oh, can you please tell me what does that part do? and where can I find proper documentation about this?

Comment: it doesn't change the model architecture at all. It just makes a subset of variables trainable - perhaps, to feed a few epoch of domain-specific training data to improve performance in that specific domain

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't actually delete layers from the model architecture. However, you can freeze layers that you do not want to be trained. So the layer you freeze is not trained and the parameters on that layer are not updated

You can see the layers with this;

```
bert_model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
print(bert_model)
#or
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    print(name)
```

You can also freeze a layer or more than one layer like this:

```
for name, param in self.model.named_parameters():
    if 'classifier' not in name:
        param.requires_grad = False
```

In example the script above will freeze all layers since it does not contain any layer "classifier" expression and you can get just embedding vectors from bert's output. Apart from this, there is no need to specify a trainable layer, because the layers that you have not already frozen will continue to train.

You can also check out all of bert's heads and layer structures from this [document](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v2.0.0/_modules/transformers/modeling_bert.html)